# Windows seems to recognize a directory as a file. Is there a way to change it?

Tags: windows, file, directory, archive

I've recently tried downloading polarssl from here :

https://polarssl.org/download/polarssl-1.2.8-gpl.tgz

My winrar (on Windows Vista) opens the archive which seems to contain a single FILE. While in the winrar I can open it as if it was a directory, leading me to think that it's either a double archive or a directory which windows somehow erroneously takes as a file. However when I extract it (and not the contents of it), windows sees it as a file without an extension (and is unable to open it in any way).

Is the file a directory and if so how do I let windows know that it is one ? Is it perchance a double archive ?

I tried to google to no avail. Hope it's not a too newbish question :)

Comment: Stop using WinRAR. Clearly it's handling this archive stupidly.

Comment: `.tgz` is short for `.tar.gz` which **is** double archived. Except not, because `.tar` is the archiving part (i.e. a directory structure bundled together into a single file), and `.gz` is the compression part. (This is because archiving and compression are two orthogonal tasks and  those Linux tools choose to handle those separately.) A nonbad GUI archiver should, however, handle a `.tar.gz` as it would do any other compressed archive. It seems that in your case WinRAR only does the decompression step, but unhelpfully doesn't append `.tar` to the decompressed file.

Comment: (That said, this implies that renaming your original compressed archive to `.tar.gz`, or adding `.tar` to the uncompressed archive will help you.)

Comment: Aye, that's a good explanation, thank you. Sorry for the stupid question, WinRAR just got me somewhat confused :) Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it ? Thanks, again.

Comment: Done, with some editing to make the explanation hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tgz` is a shortened file extension for `.tar.gz` (possibly for use on operating systems / filesystems that have trouble with a double file extension) which is, indeed "double archived". More precisely, it means that a directory and its contents first got *archived* into a `.tar` file. Then this file got *compressed* as a whole into a `.gz` file. (Many compression programs / formats like `.zip` and `.7z` do both archiving and compression at once. However, archiving and compression are orthogonal, and in the land of Unix/Linux tools, are performed by different programs.)

The correct way of handling this format, regardless of which extension variant is used, in a GUI archiver would be decompressing it into a `.tar` file, that you could then unarchive. Alternately, handle it in the intuitive way that one would expect for a ZIP file and just decompress and unarchive in one go. WinRAR seems to do something silly, which is uncompress a `foo.tgz` file not into `foo.tar`, but merely strips the extensions and outputs `foo`.

A long-term solution would be getting a less bad archiver ;) However, either renaming `foo.tgz` into `.tar.gz` before decompressing, or renaming the extensionless `foo` into `foo.tar` should let you continue working with the file.